# Is there a size limit of email message I can put in through "Create draft email" web API (Screen CO409010)?

Tags: acumatica

There seems to be size limit of the message I can put in as draft email through WEB API - I was trying to create a draft email message under "Organization" -> "Communications" -> "Email" -> "Draft" through Web API and My code is as follows:

```
            CO409010Content CO409010 = context.CO409010GetSchema();
            context.CO409010Clear();

            List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();

            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = email.FromAddress, LinkedCommand = CO409010.Emails.From });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = email.ToAddress, LinkedCommand = CO409010.Emails.To});
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = email.Subject, LinkedCommand = CO409010.Emails.Subject });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = email.Message.Substring(0, 10000), LinkedCommand = CO409010.Emails.NoteText });


            cmds.Add(CO409010.Actions.Save);
```

The code above worked because I keep the email message within 10000 characters, and it gave me error as below when I didn't limit the size of the message:

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at PX.Reports.Parser.ExpressionParser.b(String A_0)
   at PX.Reports.Parser.ExpressionParser..ctor(String text)

By the way, this problem also happens when I tried to add message to opportunity through web API (screen id CR304000), and I don't have any problem with manually entering a long message into a draft email or opportunity.

Is there a size limit of the message that can be put in through WEB API? It seems within 10,000 characters would be OK but not OK if it's more than 10,000.

Comment: what version of Acumatica do you use?

Comment: Could you give text example which fails this code? I tried to reproduce this issue but it works without exception on random text.

Comment: Weird..I replaced my text, which was a long email including French characters in html format, with a long random string, and I didn't get that  error, although the email wasn't created successfully but I guess that is a separate issue. Do I need to escape or do some encoding before I add html text into the email message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. The problem has been resolved after I removed all the newlines ("\r\n") from my HTML format email message before I put that message into "CO409010.Emails.NoteText" field, although I still don't understand why system doesn't do it itself since that is obvious that all email messages will contain newlines. I think that may be a bug in Acumatica.

Anyway, thanks to @Kirill Bestemyanov for his response that reminded me that problem might reside in content.